# A question about Vector Calculus in Electrodynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, vector-fields, calculus

In "Modern Electrodynamics" by Zangwill, on page $91$ equation $(4.3)$ implies that: $$(\vec{r} \cdot \nabla)^n=r_i \ r_j \ r_k \ldots\partial i \  \partial j \  \partial k \ldots \ \ ,$$
where $\vec{r}$ is a position vector. However, when explicitly expanding the dot product, I am obtaining extra terms - cosider a $3$-D position vector with $n=2$:

$$(\vec{r}\cdot \nabla)^2=(x\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial }{\partial y}+z \frac{\partial }{\partial z})(x\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial }{\partial y}+z \frac{\partial }{\partial z})$$
So in particular, the first product of terms yields (applying the product rule):

$$x\frac {\partial}{\partial x}(x\frac {\partial}{\partial x}) =x(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x\frac {\partial^2}{\partial x^2})=x(1 \cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x\frac {\partial^2}{\partial x^2})=x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x^2\frac {\partial^2}{\partial x^2},$$
and it is immediately clear $x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ term is not included in the equation $(4.3)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that's not supposed to be $(\vec r' \cdot \nabla)^n$? The derivative is with respect to the unprimed coordinates, so e.g. $\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}=0$.

To make it somewhat more obvious, we can replace $\vec r'$ with, say, $\vec b$, to yield the expressions

$$\frac{1}{|\vec r - \vec b|} = \frac{1}{r} + \vec b \cdot \nabla \frac{1}{r} + \frac{1}{2}(\vec b \cdot \nabla)^2 \frac{1}{r} + \ldots \tag{4.2}$$
and
$$(\vec b \cdot \nabla)^n = b_{i}b_{j}b_k\ldots \partial_i\partial_j\partial_k\ldots$$

Comment: I can't find it now, but I believe Zangwill says somewhere before p. 91 that $(\vec{r} \cdot \nabla)^n=r_i  r_j  r_k \ldots \partial_i   \partial_j   \partial_k \ldots$ is notation used for convenience (i.e. it's understood the derivatives pass through).